# Getting element from priority_queue using member function top()

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, priority-queue

Good day to everyone!
I have:

*"ClassA.h"*

```
class ClassA
{
....
public:
priority_queue<OBJECT*, vector<OBJECT*>, compound_objectNS::compare>  m_prior_queue_Objects; 
....
}
```

*"ClassB.h"*

```
class ClassB
{
void someFunction(void);
ClassA* m_network;
}
```

*"ClassB.cpp"*

```
void ClassB::someFunction(void)
{
vector<Compound_object*>::const_iterator vit;
vit = this->m_network->m_prior_queue_Objects.top();
```

- and here I get from iSense - **Error no operator "=" matches this operands**.
  What is wrong?!
  }

Update: typedef Compound_object* OBJECT*

Comment: In the future, please take care to post _working_ code in your questions. In this question you declare `m_network` as a direct object instance, but you use the pointer access operator `->` to access its members.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I shall follow you advice

Comment: It doesn't have to be complete, your example code here is good, but things like simple syntax errors kind of stand out to experienced programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`priority_queue::top()` returns a const reference to an element, and you are trying to assign to an iterator. You can do two things:

Instantiate a (const or non-const) pointer from the const reference to pointer:

```
OBJECT* p = priority_queue::top();
```

Instantiate a const reference to pointer from the return.

```
const OBJECT*& r = priority_queue::top();
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, actually I tried to get iterator on element and to pass it to other function, now after reading you answer I have realised that it was bad idea, why trying to pass iterator if instead of it I can pass object by reference ))

Comment: @spin_eight you can pass a reference, but you have to be sure it will remain valid.

Comment: And by the way, iterator is just a pointer on the object, so I can pass iterator to function?? Am I right?

Comment: @spin_eight pointers are iterators, but iterators aren't pointers. If your function does not expect an iterator, you cannot pass one.

Answer (score 1):

`top`'s declaration:

```
const value_type& top ( ) const
```

---

So, `top` will return `const OBJECT*&` to the "top" object.

You're trying to assign this to `vector<Compound_object*>::const_iterator`.

Change `vit`'s type to `const OBJECT*` to compile it.

---

You cannot iterate through a `priority_queue`.

Comment: I know that I can`t iterate over priority queue, but my question is not about iteration. I need to get iterator on some element of queue

Answer (score 0):

The types of `m_prior_queue_Objects.top()` and `vit` are different, so the `operator=` can't be used.